# How to give shadow to a border

Tags: css

How to give shadow to a border?

css codes:

```
p{
  border-right:2px solid black;
  line-height:4em
}
```

Now is it possible to give shadow to this border?

Comment: You can give the element a shadow but not a part of it, e.g. border

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on what type of shadow do you want to achieve

### Dynamically generate the border and add the shadow

```css
p {
    line-height:4em;
    position: relative;
}

p::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 2px;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<p>Stack Overflow</p>
```

### Simple offset shadow to the right

```css
p {
    border-right:2px solid black;
    line-height:4em;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px red;
}
```

```html
<p>Stack overflow</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```css
p {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  line-height:4em;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -moz-box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
```

Or try `:after` and [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
p {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  line-height:4em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

p:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 10%;
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #aaa, transparent);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p{
    border-right:2px solid black;
    line-height:4em;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
}
```

Comment: This is a shadow on the paragraph. I think he wants to add a shadow on the right border (a line) itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `box-shadow`.

**General Example**

```css
p {
  border:2px dashed #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>some content</p>
```

**Example for right shadow**

```css
p {
  border:2px dashed #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>some content</p>
```

A tool to generate a box-shadow you can find here: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

**From the official specification**

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the box. The property accepts either the ‘none’ value, which indicates no shadows, or a comma-separated list of shadows, ordered front to back.
>   https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#box-shadow

Answer (score 2):

Just add `box-shadow` property, like below

```css
p{
  border-right:2px solid black;
  line-height:4em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0  red;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0  red;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0  red;
  width: 200px; /* for demo purpose only*/
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, fugit!</p>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/pnajhz9g/

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
.shadow{
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px black;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<p class="shadow">Shadow for me</p>

</body>
</html>
```

this will add for the whole width.

**Note**
for more details, this is the css syntax

```
box-shadow: none|h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit;
```

none :Default value. No shadow is displayed

h-shadow :Required. The position of the horizontal shadow. Negative values are allowed.

v-shadow :Required. The position of the vertical shadow. Negative values are allowed.

blur :Optional. The blur distance.

spread: Optional. The size of shadow. Negative values are allowed.

Comment: This is a shadow on the paragraph. I think he wants to add a shadow on the right border (a line) itself. Not to mention that this solution was already posted multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
    line-height:4em;
    position: relative;
}

p::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 2px;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<p>Stack Overflow</p>
```